# CSS set max image size for certain area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware of the ability with CSS to make images resize using the following techniques:

```
img {width:100%; height: auto; }
img {max-width: 600px}
```

This works well, but the problem with it is that it applies to *everything* on the page, when I want certain images restricted to one size (say width=50px) and others up to 600px.  Can I do this in CSS, or do I need to be looking at JS for this?

Comment: Do that in CSS, try to learn how to use id and class selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target specific elements using CSS selectors, typically a specific element using `id` or many elements with similar characteristics using `class`, however CSS allows for fairly complex rules to be created to allow you to target a single specific or subset of elements.

HTML

```
<img class='large' src='123.png' />
<img class='small' src='456.png' />
<img class='unique' src='789.png' />
```

CSS

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
.large {
    max-width: 600px;
}
.small {
    max-width: 300px;
}
#unique {
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

[**Getting started with CSS from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started)

[**more on CSS selectors from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: @N.Soong - I've added some links, I'd suggest you start with these, the answers to your questions are likely too extensive for the scope of SO

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways, one you can give on HTML within div tag(if you are using it) like this

```
 <div class="usr_img_div">
                <img src="~/Images/username.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;" />
            </div>
```

where you can set height and width as your desired size and make sure the div(usr_img_div) must be defined like this

```
.usr_img_div {
height: 80%;
width: 12%;
float: left;
}
```

by doing this it will take users height and width and fit into exact space where you need used in img src where height and width is 100%; clarity of that image will be maintained without blur

Answer (score 0):

Define a class or id attribute to the image that you want to resize. You do not need to mention height as it will automatically adjusted.  For Example:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="test1" />
<img src="image.jpg" class="test2" />

<style>
.test1
{
width:50px;
}

.test2
{
width:650px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS, but take care when you use px because the container can be smaller than 600px (for example). I suggest you to use in this case %.
  So you don't need JS for it. CSS is enough